# Variable Me.Filter in Access with multiple Criterias

Tags: vba, ms-access

I built a form in Access to filter the form of a database. I did it with the me.filter which is based on a search field the user types in.

It works with one filter which includes about 30 objects that can be filtered. One of those looks like this:

```vb
Sub Filter()
Dim Category As Variant
Dim Search As Variant 

Category = Field118 'Category in which the user chooses the field, in which he wants to filtrer
Search = Text110 'Word that should be filter

If Category = "Year" Then
    Me.Filter = "Year Like ""*" & Search & "*"""
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

I want to include a second filter, which filters the first one. I created a new Category and Search Box (now I have two) and created the following code for the second boxes, which should filter the already filtered form:

```vb
Sub Filter2()

If Category = "Brand" Then
Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " And [Brand] Like "" * " & Search & " * """
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

I did a second sub, so the filter is just used when the user uses the second filter. I get no error but the filter is showing no data.

Comment: Do you need the spaces after the wildcards

Comment: Don't append to the Filter, just build a whole filter string. There is no need for multiple procedures, one can serve. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164483/filter-a-form-based-on-concatrelated. Agree with @Nathan_Sav - don't put spaces around the asterisk wildcards.

Comment: The spaces after the wildcards were added automatically by Access. Now i did it without spaces, but its still not working. The problem with one whole filter string is that the user does not use a multiple filter criteria every time. The second filter should be optional. Therefore i wanted to build a simple me.filter and just if the user uses the second one to concatenate it with the first one. With just one whole filter string this would not work for me, since the filter would apply automatically both criterias.

Comment: Use single quotation marks to wrap your strings (inside the double). `" And [Brand] Like '*" & Search & "*'"`. You also need to check if the filter string is not empty before joining them with the `AND` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, Year is a number (should be), so try:

```vb
Me.Filter = "Year = " & Search & ""

' and later
Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " And [Brand] Like ""*" & Search & "*"""
```

That should set the *Filter* to something like:

```
Year = 2019 And [Brand] Like "*Lego*"
```

Comment: The year was a string, since i had no calculations with it. Nonetheless Kostas solution worked for me! Thank you very much for your help! Have a nice day!

Comment: OK. Just make sure you no have brand names including a single-quote.